# Multiple manipulations to the same variable using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How can make I several, sequential manipulations of the same variable using dplyr, but more elegantly than the code below?

Specifically, I would like to remove the multiple calls to `car_names =` without having to nest any of the functions.

```
     mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% mutate(car_names = row.names(.)) %>% 
        mutate(car_names=stri_extract_first_words(car_names)) %>% 
mutate(car_names=as.factor(car_names)
```

Comment: What about `mutate(car_names=as.factor(stri_extract_first_words(row.names(.))))`?

Comment: You could do `mtcars %>% mutate(car_names = row.names(.),     car_names=stri_extract_first_words(car_names),
car_names=as.factor(car_names)`. That's a single call to `mutate` but you still have to call `car_names =`if you want to change it multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to type less and not nest the function, you can use the pipe inside the `mutate` call :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

# What you did
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(car_names = row.names(.)) %>% 
  mutate(car_names = stri_extract_first_words(car_names)) %>% 
  mutate(car_names = as.factor(car_names))

# Another way with less typing and no nesting       
mtcars3 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(car_names = rownames(.) %>% 
           stri_extract_first_words(.) %>% 
           as.factor(.))

identical(mtcars2, mtcars3)
[1] TRUE
```